# Spark/Hive - Group data into a "pivot-table" format

Tags: hive, pyspark, avro, emr, parquet

I have a very annoying set of files structured like so:

```
userId string,
eventType string,
source string,
errorCode string,
startDate timestamp,
endDate timestamp
```

Each file may contain an arbitrary number of records per eventId, with varying eventTypes and sources, and different code and start/end date for each.

Is there a way in Hive or Spark to group all of these together on userId, sort of like a key-value, where the value is the list of all fields associated with the userId? Specifically, I'd like it to be keyed by eventType and source. Basically I want to trade table length for width, sort of like a pivot table. My goal for this is to eventually be stored as Apache Parquet or Avro file format for more speedy analysis in the future.

Here's an example:

Source data:

```
userId, eventType, source, errorCode, startDate, endDate
552113, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.432', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.452'
284723, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.675', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.775'
552113, 'TRADE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:47.221', '2017-09-01 12:01:46.229'
552113, 'CHARGE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.123', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.976'
284723, 'REFUND', 'MERCH', 1, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.275', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.947'
552113, 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:49.908', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.623'
284723, 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:50.112', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.777'
```

Goal:

```
userId, eventTypeAckProvider, sourceAckProvider, errorCodeAckProvider, startDateAckProvider, endDateAckProvider, eventTypeTradeMerch, sourceTradeMerch, errorCodeTradeMerch, startDateTradeMerch, endDateTradeMerch, eventTypeChargeMerch, sourceChargeMerch, errorCodeChargeMerch, startDateChargeMerch, endDateChargeMerch, eventTypeCloseProvider, sourceCloseProvider, errorCodeCloseProvider, startDateCloseProvider, endDateCloseProvider, eventTypeRefundMerch, sourceRefundMerch, errorCodeRefundMerch, startDateRefundMerch, endDateRefundMerch
552113, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.432', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.452', 'TRADE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:47.221', '2017-09-01 12:01:46.229', 'CHARGE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.123', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.976', 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:49.908', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.623', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
284723, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.675', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.775', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:50.112', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.777', 'REFUND', 'MERCH', 1, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.275', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.947'
```

The field names or order doesn't matter, as long as I can distinguish them.

I've tried two methods already to get this to work:

1. Manually select each combination from the table and join to a master dataset. This works just fine, and parallelizes well, but doesn't allow for an arbitrary number of values for the key fields, and requires the schema to be predefined.
2. Use Spark to create a dictionary of key:value records where each value is a dictionary. Basically loop through the dataset, add a new key to the dictionary if it doesn't exist, and for that entry, add a new field to the value-dictionary if it doesn't exist. This works beautifully, but is extremely slow and doesn't parallelize well, if it does at all. Also I am not sure whether that would be a Avro/Parquet compatible format.

Are there any alternatives to those two methods? Or even a better structure than what my goal is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to have something like this?

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col, create_map, collect_list

df = sc.parallelize([
    ['552113', 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.432', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.452'],
    ['284723', 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.675', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.775'],
    ['552113', 'TRADE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:47.221', '2017-09-01 12:01:46.229'],
    ['552113', 'CHARGE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.123', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.976'],
    ['284723', 'REFUND', 'MERCH', 1, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.275', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.947'],
    ['552113', 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:49.908', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.623'],
    ['284723', 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:50.112', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.777']
]).toDF(('userId', 'eventType', 'source', 'errorCode', 'startDate', 'endDate'))
df.show()

new_df = df.withColumn("eventType_source", struct([col('eventType'), col('source')])).\
    withColumn("errorCode_startEndDate", struct([col('errorCode'), col('startDate'), col('endDate')]))

new_df = new_df.groupBy('userId').agg(collect_list(create_map(col('eventType_source'), col('errorCode_startEndDate'))).alias('event_detail'))
new_df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it could work! I tried it out on my live dataset and it returns pretty much what I wanted, in terms of how it is grouped. Though, I'm not familiar with the "list of maps" data structure, and can't find anything documented anywhere on its operations. I suppose a followup question would be, How do I interact with this data structure? As an example, how can I get the CHARGE/MERCH attributes for a specific user?

Comment: Glad that it helped! I think this may help get started with the follow up question: `from itertools import chain;

new_df.printSchema();
rdd1 =  new_df.where(col('userId') == '552113').select('event_detail').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: chain(*(x)));
keys = rdd1.map(lambda x: x.keys()).collect();
values = rdd1.map(lambda x: x.values()).collect();` `keys` and `values` are the one which needs to be looked into.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and give your comments,

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *

>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

>>> l=[(552113, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.432', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.452'),(284723, 'ACK', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:45.675', '2017-09-01 12:01:45.775'),(552113, 'TRADE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:47.221', '2017-09-01 12:01:46.229'),(552113, 'CHARGE', 'MERCH', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.123', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.976'),(284723, 'REFUND', 'MERCH', 1, '2017-09-01 12:01:48.275', '2017-09-01 12:01:48.947'),(552113, 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:49.908', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.623'),(284723, 'CLOSE', 'PROVIDER', 0, '2017-09-01 12:01:50.112', '2017-09-01 12:01:50.777')]

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['userId', 'eventType', 'source', 'errorCode', 'startDate','endDate'])
>>> df.show(10,False)
+------+---------+--------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|userId|eventType|source  |errorCode|startDate              |endDate                |
+------+---------+--------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|552113|ACK      |PROVIDER|0        |2017-09-01 12:01:45.432|2017-09-01 12:01:45.452|
|284723|ACK      |PROVIDER|0        |2017-09-01 12:01:45.675|2017-09-01 12:01:45.775|
|552113|TRADE    |MERCH   |0        |2017-09-01 12:01:47.221|2017-09-01 12:01:46.229|
|552113|CHARGE   |MERCH   |0        |2017-09-01 12:01:48.123|2017-09-01 12:01:48.976|
|284723|REFUND   |MERCH   |1        |2017-09-01 12:01:48.275|2017-09-01 12:01:48.947|
|552113|CLOSE    |PROVIDER|0        |2017-09-01 12:01:49.908|2017-09-01 12:01:50.623|
|284723|CLOSE    |PROVIDER|0        |2017-09-01 12:01:50.112|2017-09-01 12:01:50.777|
+------+---------+--------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+

>>> myudf = F.udf(lambda *cols : cols,ArrayType(StringType())) #composition to create rowwise list
>>> df1 = df.select('userId',myudf('eventType', 'source', 'errorCode','startDate', 'endDate').alias('val_list'))

>>> df2 = df1.groupby('userId').agg(F.collect_list('val_list')) # grouped on userId

>>> eventtypes = ['ACK','TRADE','CHARGE','CLOSE','REFUND'] # eventtypes and the order required in output

>>> def f(Vals):
        aggVals = [typ for x in eventtypes for typ in Vals if typ[0] == x] # to order the grouped data based on eventtypes above
        if len(aggVals) == 5:
            return aggVals
        else:
            missngval = [(idx,val) for idx,val in enumerate(eventtypes)if val not in zip(*aggVals)[0]] # get missing eventtypes with their index to create null
            for idx,val in missngval:
                aggVals.insert(idx,[None]*5)
            return aggVals

>>> myudf2 = F.udf(f,ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
>>> df3 = df2.select('userId',myudf2('agg_list').alias('values'))

>>> df4 = df3.select(['userId']+[df3['values'][i][x] for i in range(5) for x in range(5)]) # to select from Array[Array]

>>> oldnames = df4.columns
>>> destnames = ['userId', 'eventTypeAckProvider', 'sourceAckProvider', 'errorCodeAckProvider', 'startDateAckProvider', 'endDateAckProvider', 'eventTypeTradeMerch', 'sourceTradeMerch', 'errorCodeTradeMerch', 'startDateTradeMerch', 'endDateTradeMerch', 'eventTypeChargeMerch', 'sourceChargeMerch', 'errorCodeChargeMerch', 'startDateChargeMerch', 'endDateChargeMerch', 'eventTypeCloseProvider', 'sourceCloseProvider', 'errorCodeCloseProvider', 'startDateCloseProvider', 'endDateCloseProvider', 'eventTypeRefundMerch', 'sourceRefundMerch', 'errorCodeRefundMerch', 'startDateRefundMerch', 'endDateRefundMerch']

>>> finalDF = reduce(lambda d,idx : d.withColumnRenamed(oldnames[idx],destnames[idx]),range(len(oldnames)),df4) # Renaming the columns
>>> finalDF.show()    
+------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|userId|eventTypeAckProvider|sourceAckProvider|errorCodeAckProvider|startDateAckProvider   |endDateAckProvider     |eventTypeTradeMerch|sourceTradeMerch|errorCodeTradeMerch|startDateTradeMerch    |endDateTradeMerch      |eventTypeChargeMerch|sourceChargeMerch|errorCodeChargeMerch|startDateChargeMerch   |endDateChargeMerch     |eventTypeCloseProvider|sourceCloseProvider|errorCodeCloseProvider|startDateCloseProvider |endDateCloseProvider   |eventTypeRefundMerch|sourceRefundMerch|errorCodeRefundMerch|startDateRefundMerch   |endDateRefundMerch     |
+------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|284723|ACK                 |PROVIDER         |0                   |2017-09-01 12:01:45.675|2017-09-01 12:01:45.775|null               |null            |null               |null                   |null                   |null                |null             |null                |null                   |null                   |CLOSE                 |PROVIDER           |0                     |2017-09-01 12:01:50.112|2017-09-01 12:01:50.777|REFUND              |MERCH            |1                   |2017-09-01 12:01:48.275|2017-09-01 12:01:48.947|
|552113|ACK                 |PROVIDER         |0                   |2017-09-01 12:01:45.432|2017-09-01 12:01:45.452|TRADE              |MERCH           |0                  |2017-09-01 12:01:47.221|2017-09-01 12:01:46.229|CHARGE              |MERCH            |0                   |2017-09-01 12:01:48.123|2017-09-01 12:01:48.976|CLOSE                 |PROVIDER           |0                     |2017-09-01 12:01:49.908|2017-09-01 12:01:50.623|null                |null             |null                |null                   |null                   |
+------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```